# Debug.WriteLine from Logging Assembly in Release Mode not writing to debug output in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, logging

My logging library has a simple `DebugLogger` that looks like this:

```
public class DebugLogger : Logger
{
    protected override void PerformLogging(string entry)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}
```

The logging library has been built in `RELEASE` mode.

An application that references the logging library is being developed in `DEBUG` mode, naturally.

The problem is that when the application using the logging library calls `DebugLogger.PerformLogging("some debug message")` nothing shows up in the Visual Studio debug output.

I have verified things do work as expected when the logging assembly is built in `DEBUG` mode.

I was expecting that that the entry assembly being in `DEBUG` mode would take precedence, but it looks like this is not the case.

Is there anything that can be done?

## edit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x31ezs1.aspx in the remarks section talks about the compiler ignoring Debug methods without `DEBUG` being defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the `Debug.WriteLine` call is processed is determined when the project containing the call is compiled.  In this case the C# compiler sees a call to `Debug.WriteLine` in a Release project (`DEBUG` not defined) and hence doesn't emit the call into the resulting IL.  At this point the `PerformLogging` method has no reference to `Debug.WriteLine` and hence no call from a build of any type will execute a `Debug.WriteLine` call.

Answer (score 4):

While you still have to define DEBUG - you don't have to do it assembly wide. You can define it only in the source files that you want. So if you want debug logging from a particular class you can define DEBUG just for that source file.

```
#define DEBUG
using System.Diagnostics;

...

class Logger
{
    void Log( string msg ){ Debug.WriteLine( msg ); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x31ezs1.aspx

> In Visual Studio C# and Visual Basic projects, by default, the "DEBUG"
>   conditional compilation symbol is defined for debug builds, and the
>   "TRACE" symbol is defined for both debug and release builds.

I created a TraceLogger that uses Trace.Writeline and that seems to be doing the trick for me.

I'm still open to suggestions.